# How to generate certificates with Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, certificate, x509

i am currently working on an API endpoint with Spring Boot for creating Secretkeys / keypairs.

This is my code for generating a keypair:

```
public static KeyPair createKeyPair(final String algorithm, final String cryptoProvider, final int keySize) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    checkCryptoProvider(cryptoProvider);
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(algorithm, cryptoProvider);
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(keySize);
    keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    return keyPair;
}
```

Now if i want to save the private key into a keystore, I need a certificate for that, but i don't know how to get that.
I saw an example with BouncyCastle which might work, but i wonder if there is a possibility to do so with Sun provider? In the documentation I only found methods for reading and validating some existing certificates from the file system etc.

Comment: Welcome to the community. We generally do not answer programming-related questions, this looks like something for StackOverflow..